# Why does (Layered)GraphPlot lose labels and renumber vertices?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

I define a graph of numbers as vertices, but also labeled, like `g=Graph[{Labeled[1 \[DirectedEdge] 5, "text1"]…},VertexLabels -> {79 -> "text2",…}]`. This is immediately plotted in the output, and that plot is labeled correctly (both vertices and edges, the original numbers used for vertices don't even show up). Then when I plot it with `LayeredGraphPlot[g, VertexLabeling -> Tooltip,EdgeLabeling -> Automatic]`, the numbers showing up as vertex label tooltips are neither the defined labels, nor even the original vertex numbers, but integers (not even in an obvious order). This makes it the plot very misleading and hard to parse. What goes wrong here, and how to do it better?

If I ask for `EdgeLabeling` too, the edge labels don't show up, so the plot lost them as well. Why?

This behavior is the same with more basic GraphPlot or the more specific LayeredGraphPlot.

See this toy example:

```
g = Graph[{Labeled[1 \[DirectedEdge] 5, "text1"]}, 
  VertexLabels -> {1 -> "text2", 5 \[DirectedEdge] "text3"}]
LayeredGraphPlot[g, VertexLabeling -> Tooltip, 
 EdgeLabeling -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Can you give a complete example please?

Comment: @Szabolcs Point taken, now you have the working example.

Comment: This is likely because `*GraphPlot` functions are the old way to visualize a graph, from before when Mathematica got a `Graph` datatype.  I'd consider them deprecated.  Originally they just took a pair-list or a rule-list, not a `Graph`.  They've been updated to support Graph, but it seems the conversion loses both labels and names, and keeps only vertex indices.  You can either convert on your own (`Rule@@@EdgeList[g]` will be accepted by `GraphPlot`), or you can use the new way to visualize the graph, `SetProperty[g, GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding"]`.

Comment: Sorry, no time to dig into this ... that's why this is only a comment.  In short, I think the only reason `GraphPlot` functions are still around is backwards compatibility...

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. `GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding"` does help. But for my more complicated use case, it messed up the layers, while obsolete/deprecated LayeredGraphPlot was more helpful with a proper tree structure with edges always pointing downwards (e.g.), never upwards. Is there an ever better way? (My graph is not a proper tree, but close.)

Comment: Yes, you're right LayeredGraphPlot used to give nicer output ... I'd try converting the graph manually to a format supported by LayeredGraphPlot.

Answer (score 2):

```
g = Graph[{Labeled[1 -> 5, "text1"]}, 
  VertexLabels -> {1 -> "text2", 5 -> "text3"}]
```

[image]

You can use the undocumented option `"VertexNames"` to add vertex labels in `LayeredGraphPlot`.  Somehow, edge labels are lost when the first argument of `LayeredGraphPlot` is a graph object:

```
LayeredGraphPlot[g, VertexLabeling -> All, EdgeLabeling -> True, 
 "VertexNames" -> {"text2", "text3"}]
```

[image]

Using a list of `{edge, edgelabel}` pairs in the first argument we get the desired result:

```
LayeredGraphPlot[{Rule @@ #, PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeLabels] /. $Failed -> ""} & /@ EdgeList[g], 
  VertexLabeling -> True, EdgeLabeling -> True, "VertexNames" -> {"text2", "text3"}]
```

[image]

Another example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
{vlbls, elbls} = RandomWord["Noun", #] & /@ {8, 12};
rg = RandomGraph[{8, 12}];
eLbl = Association[# -> elbls[[EdgeIndex[rg, #]]] & /@ EdgeList[rg]];
vLbl = Association[# -> vlbls[[VertexIndex[rg, #]]] & /@ VertexList[rg]];


g0 = SetProperty[rg, { EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> eLbl[e]}, 
   VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[Framed[vLbl[v], Background -> White], Center]}, 
   ImageSize -> 700}]
```

[image]

```
LayeredGraphPlot[{Rule @@ #, PropertyValue[{g0, #}, EdgeLabels] /. $Failed -> ""} & /@ EdgeList[g0], 
  VertexLabeling -> All, EdgeLabeling -> True, "VertexNames" -> vlbls, ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

Of course, using `Graph` with the option `GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Top}` we get the desired result much more conveniently without the need for `LayeredGraphPlot`:

```
SetProperty[g0, 
 GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Top}]
```

[image]

**Note:** In version 12.0, `LayeredGraphPlot` is updated with many changes and the above method does not work. To access the legacy version of `GraphPlot` use the function `` GraphComputation`LayeredGraphPlotLegacy ``.